# sql server select subquery error

Tags: sql-server

I am running below select statement and 100% certain that the 2nd line is causing the issue since the subquery runs fine.

Is  `Where (first,second) IN` a valid statement?

The reason I am doing this query is that I will then replace the first select with a delete, so I just want to make sure I am getting the set I want.

```
select * from edit_proj_isbn e
where (e.record_id, e.proj_isbn)
IN
(
    select t_r.record_id, t_r.proj_isbn from editorial e,
    (
        select ed.record_id as record_id, substring(d.file_name, 1, 13) as epubisbn, epi.proj_isbn as proj_isbn, ed.asset_subtype as asset_subtype
        from editorial ed join doc_renditions d on ed.record_id = d.record_id join edit_proj_isbn epi on ed.record_id =  epi.record_id 
        where (ed.asset_subtype like 'epub' or ed.asset_subtype like 'updf' )
        and substring(d.file_name, 1, 13) not like epi.proj_isbn
    ) AS t_r
    where t_r.record_id=e.record_id
)
```

I get below error, with the 2nd line highlighted:

> *Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.*

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: You might not want to use the table alias `e` twice.  It could become confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Where (first,second) IN a valid statement?

No it is not a valid statement.  You need a separate `WHERE` clause for each of those.

Comment: It isn't a valid statement *in MSSQL*.

Comment: @Andreas considering its tagged sql server that is implied.

Answer (score 0):

A quick swag using a CTE:

```
with Timmy as (
  select t_r.record_id, t_r.proj_isbn from editorial e, 
  ( 
    select ed.record_id as record_id, substring(d.file_name, 1, 13) as epubisbn, epi.proj_isbn as proj_isbn, ed.asset_subtype as asset_subtype 
    from editorial ed join doc_renditions d on ed.record_id = d.record_id join edit_proj_isbn epi on ed.record_id =  epi.record_id  
    where (ed.asset_subtype like 'epub' or ed.asset_subtype like 'updf' ) 
    and substring(d.file_name, 1, 13) not like epi.proj_isbn 
  ) AS t_r 
where t_r.record_id=e.record_id )
select * from edit_proj_isbn
  where record_id in ( select t_r.record_id from Timmy ) and proj_isbn in ( select t_r.proj_isbn from Timmy )
```